# edX LMS port 8000 already in use (even after killing processes)

Tags: python, linux, django, vagrant, edx

I got the following issue when I try to run my edX LMS (port 8000):

> Error: That port is already in use

[image]

So in my vagrant account I found and did `kill -9` on process which was using 8000. But as soon as I killed them, the process was automatically restarting and using port 8000 and I am unable to run LMS.

[image]

Comment: No it didn't. Tried that. Process still automatically restarts.

Comment: this just worked.! thanks a lot to the good guys at edx groups.

sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl -c /edx/etc/supervisord.conf stop edxapp:lms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When that happens, I just do:

```
vagrant reload
```

(You will have to logout from SSH before by typing `logout`)

---

It is equivalent to:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

Comment: I've encountered issues in the past where 'vagrant halt' has *not* cleared the port, just as an FYI. 'vagrant reload' has simply given a port in use error. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I've had times on OS/X with Vagrant where I've had to kill not only the vagrant process, but also virtualbox, when vagrant reload hasn't worked.

On your machine (not the guest VM):

```
ps -eaf | fgrep -i vagrant
ps -eaf | fgrep -i virtualbox
```

Then kill all those processes and "vagrant up."

Answer (score 0):

**vagrant halt** is enough to kill all the processes related to the used port.